# Pronunciation of a (article) /ə/ vs /eɪ/

Tags: articles, determiners, emphasis, weak-forms

When to use the weak form /ə/ and when to use the weak form /eɪ/ of the article "a"? I figure if I would emphasize anything I wouldn't emphasize an article like "a", but rather, the noun (phrase) following it. But still I've heard people occasionally use /eɪ/. What's the point of that?

Comment: You'd emphasize it when you want to emphasize the distinction between ***a*** and ***the***.

Comment: And also: "Have you seen my dog?" "I saw ***a*** dog."